# Monotouch. UIlabel.AttributedText. Attributes doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

AttributedText of my UILabel rendered without attributes

```
var labelText = new NSMutableAttributedString(cell.MessageLabel.Text, underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.ByWord);
        foreach (ErrorJson error in messages[indexPath.Section].ErrorsData[indexPath.Row].errorsData.errors)
        {
            labelText.AddAttribute(CTStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor, UIColor.FromRGB(255, 230, 58), new NSRange(error.offset, error.length));
            labelText.AddAttribute(CTStringAttributeKey.UnderlineColor, UIColor.FromRGB(255, 230, 58), new NSRange(error.offset, error.length));
        }
        cell.MessageLabel.AttributedText = labelText;
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as below:

```
var labelText = new NSMutableAttributedString(cell.MessageLabel.Text, underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.Single);

var Attributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
    ForegroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 230, 58),
    UnderlineColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 230, 58),
};

foreach (ErrorJson error in messages[indexPath.Section].ErrorsData[indexPath.Row].errorsData.errors)
{
    labelText.AddAttributes(Attributes.Dictionary, new NSRange(error.offset, error.length));
}
cell.MessageLabel.AttributedText = labelText;
```

refer to [Style Text](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/text_field/style_text/)